# How to input a string for setting a background color in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to be able to pick names of colors from an Array List like 'BLUE'
and then use it to set a background color, ex. `button.setBackgroundColor(Color.arrayList.get(3))` But I know that won't work so how would I do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
public int[] listColors = new int[10];

private void initColors() {
    listColors[0] = getResources().getColor(R.color.color1);
    listColors[1] = getResources().getColor(R.color.color2);
    listColors[2] = getResources().getColor(R.color.color3);
    .
    .
}       

button.setBackgroundColor(listColors[0]);
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Define single colors:

```
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
<color name="green">#0dae68</color>
```

Create an array:

```
<color-array name="colors">
     <item>@color/white</item>
     <item>@color/black</item>
     <item>@color/green</item>
</color-array>
```

Use it in code:

```
int[] color = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.color);

for (int i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
    paint.setColor(color[i]);
    // Do something with the paint.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're searching for something like:

```
public class MyColor{
    private String name;
    private int red, green, blue;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}

...
List<MyColor> list = new ArrayList<MyColor>();
...

MyColor color = list.get(position);
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue()));
```